# Reference Request: Bunge's proof that cocomplete regular atomic categories are presheaves

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

The fact that a category is a **presheaves category** if and only if it is **cocomplete, regular and atomic** is due to Bunge but I cannot find the proof anywhere, does anybody know where it appears?

*Side question*: is there a characterization of **cocomplete atomic cartesian closed categories**?

Comment: The introduction of [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1977__18_3_291_0) suggests that it appears in her thesis, but I don't know if it is available.

Answer (score 1):

This is proven in the enriched context in Theorem 4.16 of Bunge's [Relative Functor Categories and Categories of Algebras](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869369901021) (note that she proves the dual result), and specialised to $\mathcal V = \mathbf{Set}$ in Corollary 4.19 ibid. Note, however, that her characterisation also requires well-poweredness and co-well-poweredness.